# Python/PyAudio - buffer underruns

Tags: python, pyaudio, portaudio

The code below keeps causing buffer underruns. 
synth_instance.play returns a list of interleaved stereo frames in floats (-1,1) of size (frames_num * 2).

It seems to me that stream.write doesn't write all the frames i supply it with for some reason.

I've tried using pyaudio in callback mode but I don't know how to supply it with enough frames in time. My main loop couldn't catch up with supplying the audio through a queue of audio chunks. The audio callback always ate up all the audio chunks faster than I could supply it with.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import pyaudio
import time
import struct

from synth import synth

from time import sleep
from time import clock

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

sample_rate = 44100
frames_num = 2205

synth_instance = synth();

stream = p.open(rate=sample_rate,
            channels=2,
            format=pyaudio.paFloat32,
            frames_per_buffer=frames_num,
            output=True)

while (True):

    audio = synth_instance.play_note(-12, sample_rate, frames_num)

    data = struct.pack('f'*len(audio), *audio)

    stream.write(data, frames_num)
```

Answer (score 0):

OP here. I'll post what I think is the answer for people googling about it. If I'm wrong and if someone more knowlegdeable is reading this please correct me because I'm just learning to program audio and lower level programming.

The thing is that Python is just too slow for any real-time audio stuff.

Even C can be too slow if you don't know how to optimize your code well.

If you're programming in C then for example if you use a ringbuffer to move stuff from your main loop to the audio thread then it seems that doing too many floating point operations in your main loop can cause the audio thread to catch up which causes stuttering.

So the answer is to make your main loop faster or make your audio thread slower.

Comment: we all know that python is slow, but we can do a lot of things in real-time using python, take a look [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YT-zAX3S850) `while` loop python is slow try `for`

Comment: If you're looking to write a real low-latency app then no, you probably shouldn't be using python OR you need to write your critical code in C and use extensions. Anyhow, you didn't mention what latency you're going for and what kind of operations/how you're performing them on the audio stream so it's impossible for others to say if what you're trying to do is feasible in Python.